# Gamified touch screen test

Tags: android, display, touchscreen

We have a new Android device and we'd like to get feedback about its touchscreen. Basically we want to know whether touch events are registered at the coordinates where the user expects them to be.

While we do some linearity tests, we also want to test with a group of ~10 test persons. Instead of giving them a stupid point which they shall click, I'd like a more gamified test, i.e. the test persons play a game and in the end the test persons give a statement on whether or not the game detected their touches nicely. In addition, the "game" should output a statistic about the offsets between expected pixel and actual pixel.

Such an app

- must work on Android 5
- works with a 800x480 screen resolution
- works in Landscape orientation
- a single test should complete in 3 to 5 minutes

At the moment I don't have a requirement for the price.